# Is it good to store a salt block with silica packs?

Tags: storage-method, salt

We recently started using an Himalayan salt block.  We cleaned it as per the directions, and the storage said to scrub it, dry it, let it air dry, and store it in an airtight container.

It seems clear that these storage directions are intended to make sure we keep the block as dry as possible.  I thought it would be even better to toss a silica pack or two into the airtight container, since silica packs help keep whatever is in their container dry.  The instructions certainly don't suggest doing this, presumably because silica packs aren't common items to keep around.  (If it matters, I scavenged this one from a bag of jerky we had eaten.)

Is there anything wrong with this idea?  My understanding was that the silica packs keep their silica all inside the packet, and draw the moisture into the packet, and that it shouldn't interact with the salt block at all, but there's a fine line between food chemistry and magic for me.

Should I toss a silica packet in to the container that has my salt block?

Comment: I was going to add "silica" and "salt-block" as tags, but they're both new, and I don't have the rep on this site to do it.  If any more "seasoned" hands think they're worth adding, please feel free.

Comment: I'd say that the extra silica bags were not necessary. Typical table salt is not greatly hygroscopic.

Comment: I'm not sure if a salt block is "typical". Other web sites said that it's mostly NaCl with a lot of other trace minerals, and that it's antimicrobial.  If it's truly not hygroscopic, I wonder why the instructions were so insistent about an airtight container.

Comment: I'd judge the "airtight container" business to be some CYA from the seller, and not actually necessary.  It's a block of salt; if you keep it from getting soaked or dusty, it'll be good for about 1000 years.  Heck, that block is millions of years old already, and i can assure you it wasn't stored in an airtight container that whole time.  ;-)

Comment: Mind you -- if you live somewhere very wet, like South Florida, I could see needing to keep it sealed away somewhere.  It's humid enough to make the salt block slick, and maybe harm whatever it's sitting on.

Comment: Note that many of the sorts of packages that are found in jerky and similar items are not desiccants like silica gel but rather oxygen absorbers. Jerky actually has quite a bit of water in it (around 20% if I recall correctly), so desiccants wouldn't be much use. O2 absorbers preserve flavor and prevent growth of some harmful bacteria during storage.

Comment: @FuzzyChef For what it's worth, I live in Houston.  We have gone over 100% humidity in the past, but it's not like I'm storing the salt block outside.  It will spend the rest of its life with us in a pretty well climate-controlled environment.

Comment: @bob1 Huh.  You're right.  Looking at the actual printing on the packet (other than all the giant "DO NOT EAT" in multiple languages), it does say oxygen absorber.  I'll read the fine print better in the future.

Comment: Anyway if you get a true dessicant which does not pose safety concerns then you could surely place it near your block.  Just to answer the question :)

Comment: Anecdote not answer: a Himalayan salt lamp that was left in a humid room unattended for a few weeks had some runoff that damaged the table finish it say on. This just supports keeping it dry, though, I don't know whether desiccants nearby would have helped keep it from weeping salt water :)

Comment: Depends on exact composition of the salt. I've a block of Salt lake salt that's been stable in a basement for 10 years. If your salt contains Calcium or Lithium ions it is going to be hygroscopic AKA water absorbing. The Himalayan stuff looks like it has oxidized iron as its major impurity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your climates humidity, if its too humid salt works like a big silica pack. It absorbs moisture, and you might get liquid salt runnoff. If you live in Denver Colorado, you could probably store it on your porch.

General suggestions are to wrap salt blocks in plastic wrapping.

Therefore if you double up that with an airtight container you can store it indefinitely.

Silica gel is also a form of porous sand that stores moisture and does not harm your salt block in any way. The two compounds are also separated by the silica gel packet wrapping.